# Android quickstart tutorial - 'this project contains resources that were not compiled...'

Tags: c#, android

I'm using VS Community 2017 v.15.7.5 with Xamarin stuff eg. 4.10.10.2 installed today. I create a project following a Hello, Android tutorial 'Phoneword' (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/hello-android/hello-android-quickstart?tabs=vswin) using minimum android version 5.0 Lollipop.

In activity_maim.axml I get a banner saying 'This project contains resources that were not compiled successfully, rendering might be affected.'

I have not yet added or subtracted anything to this project. How can I get rid of the banner? I have looked at other replies to similar questions - blank the Resouce.Designer.cs, clean, build and build again but still doesn't remove it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Close & reopen IDE it might work.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

- File > Invalidate Caches / Restart

*After IDE restart*

- Build > Clean Project
- Build > Rebuild Project